# SimpleTester on CodeIgniter fails with "Class 'GroupTest' not found"

Tags: unit-testing, codeigniter, simpletest

I'm trying to do a clean install SimpleTester on a new CodeIgniter application, following the instructions here: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/SimpleTester_-_Unit_testing_library

Everything's fine until step 6, when I add "simpletester" to the list of libraries that are autoloaded. As soon as I do that, visiting any page simply results in:

> Fatal error: Class 'GroupTest' not found in
>   /path/to/app/application/libraries/simpletester.php on line 84

Grepping through the code for GroupTest I only see it referenced in comments, and in a readme file which states the following:

*The GroupTest has been renamed TestSuite (see below).
It was removed completely in 1.1 in favour of this
name.*

I tried modifying line 84 to replace GroupTest with TestSuite, but then I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method TestSuite::addTestFile() in
>   /home/path/to/app/application/libraries/simpletester.php
>   on line 96

Is this a bug on their end? Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same issue. The GroupTest class can be found in test_case.php of version 1.0.1 of SimpleTest:
    http://sourceforge.net/projects/simpletest/files/simpletest/simpletest_1.0.1/

Unfortunately, simply inserting v1.0.1 into the libraries folder doesn’t solve all the world’s problems. I no longer get the “Fatal error: Class ‘GroupTest’ not found ...” error, but I do get a segmentation fault and my site no longer works.

I have briefly tried to track down the issue but to no avail.

Note: I also responded on the [CodeIgniter Wiki page containing the same question](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/210706/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a current project and found that the problem is that GroupTest was replaced with TestSuite which works a little differently.

This is the library code I use:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$libraryDir = APPPATH . 'libraries/simpletest';

if(!is_dir($libraryDir))
    exit("Simpletest must be located in \"$libraryDir\"");

require_once $libraryDir . '/unit_tester.php';
require_once $libraryDir . '/mock_objects.php';
require_once $libraryDir . '/collector.php';

class SimpleTester
{
    /**
    * What reporter should be used for display.
    * Could be either HtmlReporter, SmallReporter, MinimalReporter or ShowPasses.
    */
    public $Reporter = 'MinimalReporter';

    private $testDir;
    private $testTitle;
    private $fileExtension;

    public function __construct($params = false)
    {
        $ci =& get_instance();

        $ci->config->load('simpletester');

        if($params == false) {
            $params['runFromIPs'] = $ci->config->item('runFromIPs');
            $params['testDir'] = $ci->config->item('testDir');
            $params['fileExtension'] = $ci->config->item('fileExtension');
            $params['autorun'] = $ci->config->item('autorun');
            $params['reporter'] = $ci->config->item('reporter');
            $params['testTitle'] = $ci->config->item('testTitle');
        }

        if(isset($params['runFromIPs']) && strpos($params['runFromIPs'], $ci->input->server('SERVER_ADDR') === FALSE))
        {
            // Tests won't be run automatically from this IP.
            $params['autorun'] = FALSE;
        }

        // Check if call was an AJAX call. No point in running test
        // if not seen and may break the call.
        $header = 'CONTENT_TYPE';
        if(!empty($_SERVER[$header])) {
            // @todo Content types could be placed in config.
            $ajaxContentTypes = array('application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'multipart/form-data');
            foreach ($ajaxContentTypes as $ajaxContentType) {
                if(false !== stripos($_SERVER[$header], $ajaxContentType))
                {
                    $params['autorun'] = FALSE;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        $this->testDir = $params['testDir'];
        $this->testTitle = $params['testTitle'];
        $this->fileExtension = $params['fileExtension'];

        if(isset($params['reporter']))
            $this->Reporter = $params['reporter'];

        if($params['autorun'] == TRUE)
            echo $this->Run();
    }

    /**
    * Run the tests, returning the reporter output.
    */
    public function Run()
    {
        // Save superglobals that might be tested.
        if(isset($_SESSION)) $oldsession = $_SESSION;
        $oldrequest = $_REQUEST;
        $oldpost = $_POST;
        $oldget = $_GET;
        $oldfiles = $_FILES;
        $oldcookie = $_COOKIE;

        $test_suite = new TestSuite($this->testTitle);

        // Add files in tests_dir
        if(is_dir($this->testDir))
        {
            if($dh = opendir($this->testDir))
            {
                while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== FALSE)
                {
                    // Test if file ends with php, then include it.
                    if(substr($file, -(strlen($this->fileExtension)+1)) == '.' . $this->fileExtension)
                    {
                        $test_suite->addFile($this->testDir . "/$file");
                    }
                }
                closedir($dh);
            }
        }

        // Start the tests
        ob_start();
        $test_suite->run(new $this->Reporter);
        $output_buffer = ob_get_clean();

        // Restore superglobals
        if(isset($oldsession)) $_SESSION = $oldsession;
        $_REQUEST = $oldrequest;
        $_POST = $oldpost;
        $_GET = $oldget;
        $_FILES = $oldfiles;
        $_COOKIE = $oldcookie;

        return $output_buffer;
    }
}

// Html output reporter classes //////////////////////////////////////

/**
* Display passes
*/
class ShowPasses extends HtmlReporter
{
    function ShowPasses()
    {
        $this->HtmlReporter();
    }

    function paintPass($message)
    {
        parent::paintPass($message);
        print "<span class=\"pass\">Pass</span>: ";
        $breadcrumb = $this->getTestList();
        array_shift($breadcrumb);
        print implode("-&gt;", $breadcrumb);
        print "-&gt;$message<br />\n";
    }

    function _getCss()
    {
        return parent::_getCss() . ' .pass {color:green;}';
    }
}

/**
* Displays a tiny div in upper right corner when ok
*/
class SmallReporter extends HtmlReporter
{
    var $test_name;

    function ShowPasses()
    {
        $this->HtmlReporter();
    }

    function paintHeader($test_name)
    {
        $this->test_name = $test_name;
    }

    function paintFooter($test_name)
    {
        if($this->getFailCount() + $this->getExceptionCount() == 0)
        {
            $text = $this->getPassCount() . " tests ok";
            print "<div style=\"background-color:#F5FFA8; text-align:center; right:10px; top:30px; border:2px solid green; z-index:10; position:absolute;\">$text</div>";
        }
        else
        {
            parent::paintFooter($test_name);
            print "</div>";
        }
    }

    function paintFail($message)
    {
        static $header = FALSE;
        if(!$header)
        {
            $this->newPaintHeader();
            $header = TRUE;
        }
        parent::paintFail($message);
    }

    function newPaintHeader()
    {
        $this->sendNoCacheHeaders();
        print "<style type=\"text/css\">\n";
        print $this->_getCss() . "\n";
        print "</style>\n";
        print "<h1 style=\"background-color:red; color:white;\">$this->test_name</h1>\n";
        print "<div style=\"background-color:#FBFBF0;\">";
        flush();
    }
}

/**
* Minimal only displays on error
*/
class MinimalReporter extends SmallReporter
{
    function paintFooter($test_name)
    {
        if($this->getFailCount() + $this->getExceptionCount() != 0)
        {
            parent::paintFooter($test_name);
            print "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Works fine for me I haven't tested all the different reporters yet though. But the default one works fine.

And this is how I use it:

```
$this->load->library('simpletester');
echo $this->simpletester->Run();
```

And my config file is:

```
$config['testDir'] = APPPATH . 'tests';
$config['runFromIPs'] = '127.0.0.1';
$config['reporter'] = 'HtmlReporter';
$config['autorun'] = false;
$config['fileExtension'] = 'php';
$config['testTitle'] = 'My Unit Tests';
```

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth answer! I'll try it out when I get home and post back here.